# Installing to specific sub-version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to use pip to install a program specifically to python 3.6.4, but when I run

```
py -3.6 -m pip install package
```

It installs to 3.6.1

However, if I try to specify the specific version of 3.6 I want with

```
py -3.6.4 -m pip install package
```

It returns this output

```
Unknown option: -3
```

I'm guessing the argument for the version does not allow for the second period or something, but does someone else know a way to get around this? I'd prefer to do this without uninstalling 3.6.1

Comment: Why don't you use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for this? You can have project specific python versions if you need.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try 
/path/to/exactversionof/python.exe -m pip install <package_name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#uninstalling-python-versions)

You should isntall pyenv and run these command

```
pyenv install 3.6.4

pyenv global 3.6.4

python -m pip install package
```